# 数字以外を含む全角文字列から数字のみを抽出したい

Tags: php

数値以外の単位などを含む文字列から、数値のみを抽出する方法を教えてください。

例えば、以下のようなケースです。

- `体重６２．５ｋｇ` -> `62.5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

文字列に複数の数値が含まれている場合を考慮すると `preg_match_all()` の方が良いかも知れません。

```
$str = "身長１７８．２ｃｍ、体重６２．５ｋｇ";

$str = mb_convert_kana($str, "as");
preg_match_all('/[\d.]+/', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]);
=>
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "178.2"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "62.5"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

以下で出来ました。

```
function ExtractNumeric($str){
  $str = mb_convert_kana($str,"as");
  $str = preg_replace('/[^0-9\.]/','',$str);
  return (float)$str;
}
```